# Cannot import Google App Engine Api

Tags: php, google-app-engine, reset-password

All I need from my server is to be able to send emails to my users when they forget their password. I try the code below after installing the [Google App Engine SDK for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP) and it gives me the error

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php' (include_path='.:') in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/AppEngine/testMail.php on line 2

This is my code:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';

use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

try {
    $message = new Message();
    $message->setSender('test@gmail.com');
    $message->addTo('test@example.com');
    $message->setSubject('Example email');
    $message->setTextBody('Hello, world!');
    $message->send();
    echo 'Mail Sent';
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo 'There was an error';
}
```

I'm thinking that I did not install the engine properly but I'm lost at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things. First of all, you don't need the require_once statement. At least I've never had to use that (maybe you did need it in older versions of GAE but as far as I know, it isn't needed. Your php script is currently trying to open a directory that doesn't exist in your project.) All you need is the use google\appengine\api\mail\Message; statement.

Secondly, when you setSender, you need to make sure that your email 'test@gmail.com' is a registered email in your google app engine app -> otherwise no actual email will get sent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I've tried with and without the require_once statement, without it, it hits an error on the use statement directly underneath. The email is registered as well

Comment: Definitely don't need the require.